# Prestashop PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Tools'

Tags: class, prestashop

Having this error on latest prestashop version:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Tools' not found in /home/domain_name/config/config.inc.php:86
>     thrown in /home/domain_name/config/config.inc.php on line 86

Prestashop version is 1.7.1.2.
I tried to download this version again and replaced `config/folder`.

This didnt work.
Have no clue what to do

Comment: Try deleting `/cache/class_index.php`

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/prestashop-15/fatal-error-class-tools-not-found-in-homeconfigincphp-on-lin

Comment: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/285704-fatal-error-class-tools-not-found-in-varwwwprestashopconfigconfigincphp-on-line-66/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to install the Prestashop 1.7.1.2 by giving permission 0755 to folder. Then try to replace the config folder.

Note: Make sure that you are replaced the folder from Prestashop 1.7.x.x not from Prestashop 1.6 or 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to delete /var/cache** (for 1.7)

And/or check please:

```
File owner and permissions,
Is there classes/Tools.php?
Replace all files with the same version.
```

Comment: Not working for me, but for most people it seems its working.

Comment: Could you make sure you have free space on your host/server please?

Comment: There is plenty of space. Strange, that I finally made it work by not using docker, but copied files to my nginx server, used nginx Config from Prestashop documentation...faster solution than look for root cause for days...